# accept parentheses as a character in mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

i have to redirect some old page to new page i used below commend in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^Savane-98.htm$ savane-tc-9347-41-belgian-tapestry-throw [R=301,L]
```

it works fine but some of my old link have parentheses '()' it don't work how can i solve that . like below link

```
RewriteRule ^antique-bronze-square-end-rod-(flat-to-wall)-tapestry-wall-hanging-rod$ antique-bronze-square-end-rod-flat-to-wall-tapestry-rod [R=301,L]
```

this link don't work can anyone help me

Thanks

Comment: sorry is solved the problem with scape using `\(flat-to-wall\)`

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses are special characters in regular expressions - they denote the beginning and end of a matching group.

In order for them to be treated as literal parentheses by the regular expression engine, they need to be escaped with a backslash (`\`):

```
RewriteRule ^antique-bronze-square-end-rod-\(flat-to-wall\)-tap...
```